# How do I get a function to work in single.php

Tags: php, posts, functions, post-meta, get-the-id

I have a code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'njengah_change_post_date_programmatically');
function njengah_change_post_date_programmatically(){
$time = current_time('mysql');
 wp_update_post(
          array (
                      'ID' => 838, // ID of the post to update
                      'post_date' => $time,
                      'post_date_gmt' => get_gmt_from_date( $time )
                     )
            );
      }
```

But this code only work on function php.

The idea is, I want retrieve the ID from post meta in my current post. The post date will retrieve from current post. And the post is the latest post.

Comment: I'd guess that running this in single.php is too late: your site will already have a copy of the post in memory and working with that.

Comment: However this feels really wrong, and I don't completely understand what you're trying to do. You want to make this one specific post ID always the most recent post? There must be better ways to do that without making a database edit on every page load.

Comment: well simply put, the meta post id is id of a post-type. What I want to achieve is, when the post is published, the post-type will have the same date as it. Since I ordered the post type by date of that single.post

Comment: Ah OK: then you probably want to hook when the post is updated and put this code there, rather than as an init hook in single.php. See [What is correct way to hook when update post?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/134664) and [How to change the post author when the post is published?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/142630/3276)